# How to download nouveau source in selected directory with Portage?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I would like to download Nouveau source code. There is an `x11-drivers/xf86-video-nouveau` ebuild, but I don't want to install it(downloading is okay though).

Let's say that I want to install it into `~/nouveau-src/`. Is there a way to do it with `Portage`?

Comment: What are you fetching the source for??

Comment: Personal education - want to read them, see what it looks like.

Comment: Start at [Freedesktop - nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/).  Reconfiguring Libdrm is needed for KMS.   Setting it and using `--fetchonly` will have no effect, as @cylgalad states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `emerge --fetchonly x11-drivers/xf86-video-nouveau`
The file should be in `/usr/portage/distfiles/`

Ref.: [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Working/Portage#Installing_software)

Comment: This wants me to include "nouveau" in my VIDEO_CARDS so it can rebuild my `libdrm`. However, I don't want to, and I don't need to - I simply want to fetch the source.

Comment: Then, I'm afraid you have to download the sources manually.  [nouveau homepage](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/nouveau/)

Comment: --nodeps should fix that. I.e.: emerge --fetchonly --nodeps x11-drivers/xf86-video-nouveau